# NSAttributedString size() method returns incorrect width

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I created a custom `NSButtonCell` subclass which allows customizing padding between a button's contents. In my implementation (the full source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/CocoaComponents/blob/master/Buttons/Sources/Buttons/CustomPaddingButtonCell.swift)) I override [titleRect(forBounds:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscell/1531281-titlerect#) to position the button title:

```
var titleSize: NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: ceil(attributedTitle.size().width),
                  height: ceil(attributedTitle.size().height))
}

override func titleRect(forBounds rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
    return CGRect(x: paddingLeft,
                  y: rect.height / 2 - titleSize.height / 2,
                  width: titleSize.width,
                  height: titleSize.height)
}
```

The result doesn't look good:

[image]

To get the desired outcome I have to add an extra padding to the width:
[image]

I also tried using [boundingRect(with:options:context:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrect#) to get the size, but I got the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference: I figured out the issue. When using `attributedTitle`, it's important to specify the font of the button, so that `attributedString.size()` can calculate the necessary width correctly. I assumed that by default, calculations are based on the default font for `NSButton` but apparently that was incorrect. [See my commit](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/CocoaComponents/commit/d984b1d3eab096e8c46040bbe2338e44e9af0004) for more details.